# Ubuntu preseed partition table ignored

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, debian, kickstart, preseed

My Ubuntu install seems to ignore my partition table, I am not really sure why I got some partitions created an other ignored. here is my table:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              500 10 500 xfs                                  \
                  $primary{ }                                 \
                  $bootable{ }                                \
                  $lvmignore { }                              \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  device{ /dev/sda }                          \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /boot }                         \
                  .                                           \
              21000 20 22000 xfs $primary{ }                  \
                  $defaultignore{ }                           \
                  method{ lvm }                               \
                  device{ /dev/sda }                          \
                  vg_name{ sysvg }                            \
                  .                                           \
              5000 30 5000 xfs $lvmok{ }                      \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ root }                             \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ / }                             \
                  .                                           \
              5000 40 5000 xfs $lvmok{ }                      \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ var }                              \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /var }                          \
                  .                                           \
              500 50 500 xfs $lvmok{ }                        \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ tmp }                              \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /tmp }                          \
                  .                                           \
              500 60 500 xfs $lvmok{ }                        \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ var_tmp }                          \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /var/tmp }                      \
                  .                                           \
              2000 70 2000 xfs $lvmok{ }                      \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ log }                              \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /var/log }                      \
                  .                                           \
              500 80 500 xfs $lvmok{ }                        \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ audit }                            \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /var/log/audit }                \
                  .                                           \
              2000 90 2000 xfs $lvmok{ }                      \
                  method{ format }                            \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ home }                             \
                  filesystem{ xfs }                           \
                  mountpoint{ /home }                         \
                  .                                           \
              2000 9000 2000 linux-swap $lvmok{ }             \
                  method{ swap }                              \
                  format{ }                                   \
                  in_vg{ sysvg }                              \
                  lv_name{ swap_01 }                          \
                  .                                           \
```

and this is what I get:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    982M     0  982M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   201M  3.1M  197M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/sysvg-root  6.8G  828M  5.9G  13% /
tmpfs                  1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               472M   55M  393M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/sysvg-home   24G   33M   24G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/sysvg-tmp   533M   28M  506M   6% /tmp
/dev/mapper/sysvg-var   2.4G  229M  2.2G  10% /var
```

I am using LVM partitioning method:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
```

and `multi` as predefined partitioning recipes:

```
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select multi
```

What you think I should change to get this working?
Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Johnny, Thank you! I did post my question there for more visibility.